# React V6 route guarding and routing within component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, url-routing, react-router-dom, react-component

Im trying to use React Routing V6 for my project.

Currently im struggeling to make the authentication and routing itself to work.
the idea of my code is:

**Not authenticated user:**

redirect to /login with my login component. (only login component)

**Authenticated user:**

Load the `gameComponent` component, and the rest of links inside of `gamecomponent`, will load inside gameComponents div class named `middleContentHolder`

**examples:**

*authenticated user:*

visits url /crime -> loads gamecomponent, and within gamecomponent it loads the `crime` component.
visits url /test -> loads gamecomponent , and within gamecomponent it loads the `SideBarRight` component.

*not authenticated user:*

vitits url /crime -> not authenticated -> redirects to `/login` -> loads loginmodule only.

please note that in gamecomponent component, i do have links that will load within gamecomponent.
app.js will either load the gamecomponent, or redirect user to login if not auth.

**app.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import GameComponent from './gameComponent.jsx';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Routes, Route, Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Crime from './components/game/crime.jsx';

import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
import Login from './components/login/login.jsx';




function App() {
  return (
  
  <Router>
    <Routes>
         <Route path="/" element={<GameComponent />}>
             <PrivateRoute isAuth={true} path="crime" component={Crime}  redirectTo='/login'/>
         </Route>
     </Routes>
  </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Gamecomponent**:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
//import Component from 'react-dom';
import SideBarRight from './components/game/sideBarRight.jsx';
import SideBarLeft from './components/game/sideBarLeft.jsx';
import Crime from './components/game/crime.jsx';
import Login from './components/login/login.jsx';
import './gameComponent.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";


class GameComponent extends Component{
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    userData: {
        user: {cash:0, bank:0, weapon:'', username: 'test', locationname: 'Bankok',
        defence: 0},
        rankbar: {rankpercent: 50, rank: 'Mafia'},
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
  }


render() {
    return (
    <div className="main">
    <div className="sidebar left">
                <SideBarLeft/>

    </div>
    <div className="middleContentHolder">
        <Route path="/" element={<Crime />} />

    <Route path="/test" element={<Crime />} />
    <Route path="/crime" element={<Crime />} />
    <Route path="/test" element={<SideBarRight UserData={this.state.userData} />} />

        <div className="col-8">
            <div className="content">
            <div className="header"><span>Test...</span></div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="sidebar right">
        <SideBarRight UserData={this.state.userData}/>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
    
}



export default GameComponent;
```

`PrivateRoute`:(auth is just a dummy atm)

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useNavigate  } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './components/login/login.jsx';
import GameComponent from './gameComponent.jsx';


const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, redirectTo, isAuth, path, ...props }) => {
    isAuth = false;
    
    if(!isAuth) {
        return <Navigate to={redirectTo} />;
    }
    return <Route path={path} element={<Component />} />
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

update:

orginal auth was:in privateroute:

```
isAuth = isAuth;
```

one example of non-working code that would show what i want:

<Route path="/login" element={}>

```
     <PrivateRoute isAuth={true} path="/" component={GameComponent}  redirectTo='/login'>
              rest of routes exist in gamecomponent..
     </PrivateRoute>
```

Comment: `isAuth=false` why did you change the value of `isAuth` instead of using the value passed when the component was initialized? Because it will keep Navigating to `/login` since that values is always modified when `PrivateRoute ` starts mounting

Comment: yes  i did. but i dont get it to work anyway as intended. will update with orginal.

Comment: But What happens? You're basically giving the code but you're not mentioning the issues you're having?, It's going to be difficult to look at the code and tell what is wrong unless you specify exactly what is wrong? Please...

Comment: Any errors passed on Console?

Comment: no errors in console @MosiaThabo

Comment: Ok, I was away sorry for the late response. Can you please apply my suggestions below and give feedback on what happens? I can only suggest so far because I am not sure what the current behavior is of the code you provided. You did say it's not working but You didn't explain where it stops working or what you would expect when you perform a certain action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want `GameComponent` to load if use is authenticated, you will need to change your `App` component like this:

```
function App() {
  return (

  <Router>
    <Routes>
       <Route path="/login" element={<LoginComponent />} />
       <PrivateRoute isAuth={true} path="/" component={GameComponent}  redirectTo='/login'/>
    </Routes>
  </Router>
  );
}
```

Here we are essentially putting a switch so that we can navigate to `/login` when there is no authentication. `<Routes>` is vital here, because it will only render the component that matches the exact `path`.

Comment: will apply these, and thank you for feedback. in your code it seems like gamecomponent is loaded no matter auth. i only want gamecomponent loaded if authenticated.

Comment: switch not defined. switch is not used in react routing v6 @mosia ?

Comment: Are you not using React Router Dom? Please use react-router-dom, you'll be better off with it than react-router alone. It uses latest react-router.  You also need to note that `Switch` is capital letter.

Comment: Please refer to link, you will need to import Switch from React Router Dom https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch

Comment: Also note that I have updated the answer. GameComponent will now work only when authenticated.

Comment: Also due to your changing scenario, I had to completely change the answer.

Comment: Thanks for following up on that. I forgot that `Routes` works just like switch and will only render the component whose `path` is matched. So you can remove it. I have updated the answer as well. Please provide feedback, so that we can move forward.

Comment: thanks. now just getting  Line 37:3:  'PrivateRoute' is not defined , idk if that has something to do with it. will accept :)

Comment: You must import PrivateRoute inside App.js

Comment: it is @mosia  import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';

Comment: No man, It can't throw `PrivateRoute is not defined` if you imported it. By `PrivateRoute ` it means it can't find where `PrivateRoute ` is defined. Meaning it's also not imported.

Comment: Your response is very slow, and I can't keep up having to wait, you will need to provide a Repro of your code so that I can test it and fix it... please consider using codesandbox...

Comment: well the code is excactly as the same above. except ur changes. accepted it anyway

Comment: Cool, well done. Just make sure you use an IDE that assist you with checking errors and other things. As experienced as I am, I always look for sources and I heavily rely on my IDE or Code Editor for coding everyday. If you're using Javascript/Typescript heavily, I would highly recommend VSCode or VisualStudio.

Answer (score 4):

With the official release of React Router V6, the other answer is no longer valid. It will throw an error since `<PrivateRoute />` isn't a `<Route />`.

The proper way to do it is to refactor your `<PrivateRoute />` component like so...

```
import { Navigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom"

const PrivateRoute = (props: { children: React.ReactNode }): JSX.Element => {
  const { children } = props

  // Up to you specific app to decide how to get this value
  const isLoggedIn: boolean = localStorage.getItem('logged_user') !== null;
  const location = useLocation()

  return isLoggedIn ? (
    <>{children}</>
  ) : (
    <Navigate
      replace={true}
      to="/login"
      state={{ from: `${location.pathname}${location.search}` }}
    />
  )
}
```

Then whichever file you setup your routes in, you would do...

```
<Routes>
   <Route path="/PRIVATE" element={<PrivateRoute> <PrivatePage /> </PrivateRoute>}/>
   <Route path="/profile" element={<PrivateRoute> <ProfilePage /> </PrivateRoute>}/>
   <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />}/>
   <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />}/>
</Routes>
```

This is the proper way of doing it in V6 since only a `<Route />` can be nested in a `<Routes />`. Then your authenticated logic gets moved into the `element` prop.

As an added bonus, the `` state={{ from: `${location.pathname}${location.search}` }} `` in PrivateRoute allows you to get the URL of the page they tried to enter, but was denied. This is passed to your login page, where you can redirect them back to the URL after they authenticate.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution for newer version

Create custom middleware `<AuthGuard>` and use as wrapper

`<PrivateRoute>` not vaild for newer version as child of `<Routes>`

Error "A `<Route>` is only ever to be used as the child of `<Routes>` element"

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthGuard from "./Routes/AuthGuard";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
              <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
              <Route path='/guest-page' element={<AuthGuard isGuest={true}><h1>Guest Page</h1></AuthGuard>} />
              <Route path='/protected-page' element={<AuthGuard requireToken={true}><h1>ProtectedPage</h1></AuthGuard>} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**AuthGuard.js**

```js
import { Route, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLayoutEffect } from "react";

const ProtectedRoute = ({requireToken, guest, children, ...rest}) => {
    
    console.log(requireToken, guest, children, rest); 
    
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const hasToken = false;

    let hasAccess = (!requireToken || (requireToken && hasToken));
    let navigateTo = '/?login-rquired=true'; 

    if(guest) {
        hasAccess = !hasToken; 
        navigateTo = '/?guest=true';
        console.log("Guest > hasAccess: " + hasAccess)
    }

    if(requireToken){
        console.log("requireToken", requireToken)
    }
    
    useLayoutEffect(()=>{
        if (!hasAccess) {
            console.log("Not allowed");
            navigate(navigateTo);
        }
    },[])

    return (
        <>{ hasAccess ? children : "Login required" }</>
    )
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```